# How about an Offensive Allowed rating on the rooms

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, chat, offensive

If chat is going to have rooms where individuals are allowed to make offensive comments, then have those particular rooms labeled (maybe with an **O**) to denote this.

This way users who want clean conversation can avoid those rooms, and those people who like that kind of conversation don't have to worry about all their comments getting flagged.

This is especially important for those of us who SO from work, so we can keep our screens clean.

Comment: *Clean conversation* is a conversation with soap in your mouth?

Comment: Oh apparently it's a beta feature still not complete. Nevermind.

Comment: @perbert, maybe the thought that you might get soap in your mouth

Comment: Are there rooms in SO?  Have I been missing something?

Comment: @David, See the blog about the new chat place.

Comment: @Lance:  Thank you.  I'm going to have to start paying more attention to the blog.

Comment: This is declined for the reason that we simply don't want that offensive content in the first place.

Comment: @Marc: I want a pet unicorn that vomits Oreo ice cream. But what you want is just plain impossible.

Comment: @Toronto real LOL!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just one thing. If you look at [your profile](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/13295/lance-roberts?tab=prefs), you'll see what seems to hint at a *Ignore User* option. That way you can avoid people that you consider dirty mouthed before they even have the chance to soil your eyes.

Comment: I have no idea about the profile, but the Page Not Found image is *excellent*.

Comment: Thanks, that will make a huge difference.

Answer (score 5):

If you need to keep your screen "clean", then having a *live chatroom* open on it is an extremely bad idea.

Trust me on this. "offensive comments" are the least of your worries - conversation snippets losing their context *just* as your co-worker looks over your shoulder can be much, much more embarrassing...

And regardless, you can't depend on users being censored fast enough to keep their comments from showing up at an inopportune time. If the FCC and broadcast can't keep fleeting f-bombs out of broadcast TV, what hope do overworked chat moderators have?

Just map alt+tab to a mouse button or something.

Comment: @Shog Lance is referring to Welbog and his duck cocks chat room earlier today. I found it hilarious reading, but I can understand that that sort of language is over the top and can seriously alienate people. Some rules are definitely needed here IMO, as I think both things must be able to exist somehow - rather than having every swear word censored after a certain period of time.

Comment: @Shog9 In general I agree, although I think there is *some* merit in the idea that the "non-offensive" rooms wouldn't necessarily need censoring, but rather it would just be populated by people who (like myself) simply choose not to swear in their conversation.

Comment: @devinb: AFAIK, you can create a room and limit participants to those you know and trust, right? @Pekka: I think it's safe to say, if you choose to leave a Welbog chat room open on your desktop at work, you deserve whatever reputation you get as a result...

Comment: @Shog9 that's not my point. The Welbog chat room came up as a temporary solution and was deleted later. Having clearly defined rooms where coarse language is used is the solution to the problem IMO, but they need to be clearly defined somehow - which is why I like this suggestion.

Comment: @pekka, @shog9 - thing is if welbog want's to have his own little private party of offtopic tripe why doesn't he set up his own offsite IRC channel/BBS/whatever and stick a link on his profile. I kinda feel that using the SO infrastructure for this purpose (then no doubt moaning about censorship if banned, or the room closed) is a bit rich.

Comment: @Kev you have a good point there. It really is the question how large the group is that wishes to have unlimited coarse language at all times. But I have also seen a post containing the words "that was a dick move" being flagged. I'm all for a civil conversation but that is over the top. If that is going to be the standard, then I'm joining the protest too. Still, you have a point.

Comment: @Kev: a *fourth* place? Whoah...

Comment: @shog9 - ok...i'll bring my girlfriend online to a room so we can discuss our shopping list?

Comment: @Kev: you seem to be conflating the concepts of people using swear words and people being off-topic. Right now people I believe should be allowed to be off-topic because we are testing the whole thing, and speech at a live chat can't be completely *clean* (whatever that means) as it's, well, live and people is people. I won't go again into the discussion that words are just arbitrary arrangements of letters, and therefore not inherently bad/unclean/dirty/uncivilised.

Comment: @perbert "I won't go again into the discussion that words are just arbitrary arrangements of letters, and therefore not inherently bad/unclean/dirty/uncivilised." oh how libertarian of you. So if I call you a stupid f****** c**t for asking a question on SO you're going to let it go (and the rest of the community for that matter)?

Comment: @Kev: life is too short to get angry at what random people could write about me on the Internet.

Comment: @perbert - yes me too. But this is a community and some civility is expected?

Comment: @perbert  - I don't conflate anything. Just because there's some testing in a developer community tool what doesn't give some excuse to turn the testing process into some kind of festival of profanity and 'arbitrary arrangements of letters'. How about going and trying that on a beta forum for a Telerik product? Dude....just because you can doesn't mean you should. Don't be a moron.

Answer (score 1):

I'm less concerned about f & c bombs in the chat rooms than I am about sniping, flaming and general snidely comments about other users/mods which are less constructive to the community.

I guess if you're being an ass and are persistently dumping verbal diarrhoea into rooms such as Chat Feedback or Area51 then you're eventually going to be kicked off.

There's a time and a place for everything but I don't think having a rating system for rooms is needed. We're all clever folks and should know the difference, etiquette-wise, between the effect of yelling an obscenity in a pub watching the game as opposed to doing that in a three star Michelin restaurant. I hope.

Comment: So I guess this isn't common sense then?

Comment: Wait, which part of SO is the equivalent of a three-star restaurant now?

Comment: @shog9 - you know exactly what I mean. You wouldn't go round your customer's work place yelling c*** **ck*er just because it's your constitutional right to free speech. Why should I have to put up with that in a tool that's designed to assist me as a software development professional? If you want to be abusive or swear at folks then go do it on your own turf. Don't be a jerk.

Comment: @shog9 - FYI - I voted down this proposal, not because I'm a prude, but because there shouldn't be any need for an x-rated chat rooms for folks doing Q&A of the sort suggested on Area51 or SOFU. Why? Because if you really want to talk about duck genitalia then go somewhere else like 4chan.

Comment: heh... I down-voted it because I think it's unnecessary. Go figure... ;-)